# Android: how to catch the event when the soft keyboard pops up?

Tags: android

When the user presses editText, the soft keyboard pops up. I want to hide a view or 2 while it is on. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall Ms. Hackborn indicating that there are no events that indicate when the IME is displayed.